# How to send values from an arraylist from AsyncTask class to another class in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have the next problem, I tried to send `Arraylist<string>` values from AsyncTask class to other class call graphics but I don’t know what I do wrong and how to get `Arraylist<string>` values in the other class, because I have a lot of sintaxis errors I my code

AsyncTask class

```
public class fetch  extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<String>> {
    //v funcional


        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                    String Id ="";
                    String Time ="";
                    String Pressure="";

                    ArrayList<String> IdArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> TimeArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    ArrayList<String> PressureArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String IdS=""+IdArray;
                    String TimeS=""+TimeArray;
                    String PresureS=""+PressureArray;
                    data.set(1,TimeS);
                    data.set(2,TimeS);
                    data.set(3,TimeS);

            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result){
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Graphics.data.setText(data);

        }}
```

The graphics class

```
 public class Graphics extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static TextView data;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.graphics);

            Button firstButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.json);
            data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgTxt);
            firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    fetch process = new fetch();
                   ArrayList<String> data= process.execute();
                   data.get(1);
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you make array list static then you can access from any class .No need to pass the array list from Async class to any class.
Or 
Pass the array list by interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution
Fetch class

```
public class Fetch  extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String[][]> {
    public static int KEY = 0;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
     protected String[][] doInBackground(Void... voids) {
          HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
           String url = "http:xxxxxxx/xxx.json";
           String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
           JSONObject jsonObj = null;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                int nTiempos=jsonObj.length();
                String[] IdKeyArray = new String[nTie];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
                  IdKeyArray[i] = c.getString("Key");
                  String[][] valores={IdKeyArray};
                return valores;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return null;
   }
}
```

And this is the "call" the other class where I get the values

```
private String[][] valores;
Fetch process = new Fetch();
  process.execute();
   try {
      valores=process.get();
     } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      pm.setText(String.valueOf(valores[Fetch.Key][0]));
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create an interface which your "Graphics" implements it , and pass it to your `AsyncTask` class.
like this

```
public interface BlaBlaBla {
    void doBla(ArrayList<String> myBla);
}
```

and in your "Graphics" :

```
class Graphics extends AppCompatActivity implements BlaBlaBla {
fetch process = new fetch(this);
}
```

and for asyncClass :

```
public class fetch  extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,ArrayList<String>> {
 //constructor
BlaBlaBla bla;
public fetch(BlaBlaBla bla){
this.bla=bla;
}
//when your task is complete use bla.doBla(pass your array here);
}
```